# Incorporating logs into Splunk

Tags: 8, log-messages

As of now we are running Drupal 8 and we would like to send the Drupal logs to Splunk. I have researched several plugins for Drupal that did such a thing, unfortunately they were all for Drupal 7 and not compatible with Drupal 8.

I have looked into building my own module to do this, but its the triggering of this module where I am at a lost. It seems these modules are triggered via an URL endpoint such as /site/login.
This isnt exactly what is wanted, essentially anytime Drupal logs information we want to send that out to Splunk.

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Drupal 8 you may define your own logger implementation to do whatever you want with log messages. The default logger provided by core Drupal saves these messages in the Drupal database and makes them available in the UI at `/admin/reports/dblog`. This default logger is implemented in the core dblog module by the logger class `\Drupal\dblog\Logger\DbLog`, and that's a great example to use when you write your own.

A logger is a class that implements `LoggerInterface` and is used as a service with the 'logger' service tag. **All** registered loggers are used for every channel. You don't need to 'trigger' a logger or do anything special to have that logger automatically used by core Drupal, other than tagging the service.

The service definition for the core DbLog logger looks like this (from dblog.services.yml):

```
services:
  logger.dblog:
    class: Drupal\dblog\Logger\DbLog
    arguments: ['@database', '@logger.log_message_parser']
    tags:
      - { name: logger }
      - { name: backend_overridable }
```

You can see that the `logger.dblog` service is implemented by the `DbLog` class, and this service is tagged as a logger. That tag is how Drupal knows to send log message to this service. Without the tag, Drupal wouldn't know this service was a destination for log messages.

Another good example in core is the core syslog module, which provides a logger that uses the PHP `syslog()` function to send messages to an operating-system-dependent location (probably a flat text file shared by all other programs that log messages on that operating system).

To make your own 'Splunk' logger, you would create a module that defines a logger service, for example `logger.splunk`. (Services are defined in the module's `<modulename>.services.yml` file.) You must have a class, for example 'Splunk' that implements `LoggerInterface`. In that 'Splunk' class you may use the Splunk API to send log messages to Splunk. The details of how to do that is up to you as it has nothing to do with Drupal at this point. If you have code that sends log messages to Splunk from a standalone program then I think it is pretty clear from examples provided by core how to use that code in your logger class.

Your module will consist of a `<modulename>.info.yml` file, a `<modulename>.services.yml` file, and a `<modulename>/src/Logger/Splunk.php` file. Nothing more is needed. If you've done it right, then when you enable your module all messages should be logged to Splunk.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Splunk in partcular, but Drupal core has the syslog module that outputs log information to a flat file on the server, which Splunk could maybe then consume.

Comment: On the Pantheon documentation, they talk about using a forwarding server: https://pantheon.io/integrations/logging
Acquia includes log forwarding with certain plans:
https://docs.acquia.com/cloud-platform/monitor/logs/forwarding/

Comment: Here are some of the Splunk docs about forwarders: https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Forwarder/8.2.4/Forwarder/Abouttheuniversalforwarder